# Video header doesn't play in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

I have a problem with my header video. On Chrome and Safari it works but on firefox i have a white screen when i'm in fullscreen. Video works on firefox when my window is medium or small (it's a responsive site using bootstrap)

I read firefox needs .webm and .ogv to works, so i have these files uploaded in my assets/videos:

```
Video.mp4  
Video.ogv  
Video.webm
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work properly on firefox if it works on chrome and safari.
Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 1):

check this url https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973142#answer-488412 and http://gerardtonti.com/a-stain-in-time-video/  test url is http://html5test.com/